# Visual Basic ASP.NET 4 Request.Form()

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

this may sound like a silly question but i am learning Visual Basic ASP.NET 4 and i have been asked to create a DropDownList which obtains information from a table using SQL. I cant seem to pull the selected item from the dropdownlist and show it on the screen using Request.Form.

I have tried this..

```
Dim selItem As String = Request.Form("DDList")
Response.Write(selItem)
```

but this does not show anything on screen. Please help as i am struggling with this.

I have added my dropdownlist as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDList" runat="server" Width="201px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDList2" runat="server" Width="145px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

My Class/Function

```
Public Class sqlFunc

Public Shared Function tableData() As DataSet

    Dim oraConnect As New OracleConnection
    oraConnect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("smart_dev").ConnectionString

    Dim oraCommand As New OracleCommand

    oraCommand.Connection = oraConnect
    oraCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text

    Dim lsSQL As String = ""
    lsSQL = "SELECT code, description FROM ref_code WHERE domain = 'SPECIALTY'"

    oraCommand.CommandText = lsSQL

    Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(oraCommand)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)

    Return ds
End Function
```

What i am using on my .aspx.vb page;

```
Dim dsData1 As New DataSet
        dsData1 = tableData()


        DDList.DataSource = dsData1
        DDList.DataValueField = "code"
        DDList.DataTextField = "description"
        DDList.DataBind()
        DDList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
        DDList.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: Are your `DropDownList`'s within another containing control?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean sorry? I am using them within a class and function

Comment: On your .aspx page, are your controls within a GridView or Repeater or DataList or somthing else?

Comment: apart from what i have put on here i only have them within a <div id="dForm"> thats all. I used the Toolbox to drag a dropdownlist into the .aspx page

Comment: could you post your code to show how you are binding the data to the dropdown lists? are you re-binding the data on PostBack ?

Comment: i updated my question to show my other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get the selected value using Request.Form if you are using an asp:DropDown ASP.net control. All you have to do is:

```
Dim selItem As String = DDList.SelectedValue
Response.Write(selItem)
```

If you really want to use Request.Form, do it like this:

```
Dim selItem As String = Request.Form(DDList.ClientID)
Response.Write(selItem)
```

Also, make sure you have ViewState enabled and that you do not rebind the DropDown at PageLoad when there is a PostBack:

```
Sub Page_Load
    If Not IsPostBack
        ' Bind your DropDown here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried both of these but they do not print out anything on the screen. I tried the following  Dim selItem2 As String = Request.Form("DDList2")
        DDList2Output.Text &= selItem2 but this prints out the wrong item from my table

Comment: Before changing the selected value and posting the form, if you check the page source (with View Source), do you see the correct values and text for your options?

Comment: Also, make sure you have ViewState enabled and that you do not rebind the DropDown at PageLoad when there is a PostBack (see updated answer)